# OnPrem ADFS 3.0 (2012) and ASPNETCore API 2.0

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, adfs

I need to secure a ASPNETCore 2.0 API with OnPrem ADFS 3.0 (2012) using JWT and OAuth.

I've been scouring the web and haven't really found any good examples. Every sample I have found such as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/single-page-application-with-ad-fs) is demonstrating AD FS 2016 or Azure AD.

I also found [this](http://www.carbon60.com/blog/using-adfs-3-0-with-mvc-6-asp-net-5) example but it isn't using ASPNETCore 2.0.

Could anyone point me to an example which they found worked for them?

Comment: I am unable to find a sample to share. Please check this SO thread which might be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671692/onprem-adfs-3-0-2012-and-aspnetcore-api-2-0